# Position and size are ambiguous for “view”

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have set pin to all view but i got continuously this alert ! 
I have seen that this is because of height and width constraints but i didn't add height and width still i got this error !
This alert should be avoidable or not.

[image: i have created this view]

Comment: Could you show how it looks on builder or in code, please?

Comment: which type alert you got can you please show ?

Comment: i Have add description link of -i have created this view please check

Comment: You wrote "but i got continuously this alert !" Which alert?

Comment: Position and size are ambiguous for “view” @Amanpreet

Comment: Based on your image, it looks like that view has only maybe Left and Bottom constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UIView has no intrinsic size meaning none of your views know how large they should be and thus cannot be laid out the way you have them.  You can set the height of each one to a fixed number but if you want them to scale I recommend using Equal Heights and Equal Widths and set the multiplier to the proportion of the view you want the little views to size to be.  You could do this so many ways. 
 I am going walk you through one way that I think is the quickest(using StackViews) for my own sanity but the same logic could work with more dragging from each view.

Step 1:
Drag a Vertical StackView to the top of the storyboard.  Add the following constraints.  pin leading, trailing, and top =20.  Then drag from the vertical stack view to the main view and choose equal heights and change the multiplier to 0.6(60% of the main view height). See image
[image: Step 1 Image]

Step 2:
Add a single horizontal stackview as an arranged Subview to our vertical stack view.  Now add 3 UIViews and change the colors to desired colors.  Change stack view to Alignment-Fill and Distribution-Fill Proportionately.  Also add spacing=20.  See Image
[image: Step 2]

Step 3:
Choose your horizontal stackview that you just created in step 2 and hit Command-C to copy it.  Hit Command-V to paste it.  Note- If it does not paste it into the vertical stackview drag it in to the vertical stack view.  Not there yet but close.  See image
[image: Step3]

Step 4: Go to the vertical stack view and change it to Alignment-Fill and Distribution-(Fill Equally).  Add Spacing of 20.  You should now be a point that looks like this.  See image
[image: Step 4]

Step 5. Add a horizontal stack view below the vertical stack view and the bottom layout guide.  Pin to all four sides at 20.  Add three views and change the color to desired color.  Change Alignment-Fill, Distribution-Fill Equally, and spacing=20.
[image: Step 5]

Step 6. Adjust verticalStackView equal heights multiplier to maybe a lower number(0.5) to make it look like your view.

Step 7. Reap the rewards
[image: Step 7]

The Big takeaway is that a UIView needs to know how big it is.  UIStackView in this case tells the views how big they are.  You could just have easily set the height and width of one of your views in your screenshot above to a percentage of the view.  Then drag from that view to all of the like sized views and set equal heights/widths.  That would have been more tedious and you can see why I used Stackviews for the example.  Good luck.

Comment: you really explain me well ! Thank you @agibson007.  Its reallyy helped to undestand .thank you very much...:)

Comment: @kairashah glad it helped. I forgot to mention there are views that can control their own size. UILabel and UITextfield-if it has text and knows it’s width or height it can solve for the other. UITextView with scrolling disabled does the same. UIImageView if an image is set. There are others although generally you will still have constraints on these but you might let them grow or shrink. Just empty UIView does not know its size. Good luck.